# Multiple Entries to Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, registration

I have a registration page where a user can register him/herself along with 20 other people. Now I can store all those values in fine, the question I have is how to identify in the table. So let's say John registers himself and 20 of his friends. In the table, I would label him and his group with an ID number of 1, but I would label his ID specifically with a star so I know that he's the one who registered everyone else.

That's the idea I'm trying to get at, but I don't know how to do that in practice. What is the best way and how do I really go about doing this? I think I can write the code but I just need some concepts to work off of.

Answer (score 1):

You can create three tables for this. The `UserList` which contains all the records of all users. The `GroupList` which contains all the groups and the owner of the group. and Lastly `PersonGroup` which contains the **user_id** and the group which a certain user belongs.

```
CREATE TABLE UserList
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FullName VARCHAR(50),
    -- ... other columns if you want ...
    CONSTRAINT ul_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT ul_uq UNIQUE (FullName)
);

CREATE TABLE GroupList
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    GroupName VARCHAR(25),
    OwnerID INT,
    -- ... other columns if you want ...
    CONSTRAINT gl_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT gl_UQ UNIQUE(GroupName),
    CONSTRAINT gl_FK FOREIGN KEY (OwnerID) REFERENCES UserList(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PersonGroup
(
    RecordID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    User_ID INT,
    GROUP_ID INT,
    CONSTRAINT pg_PK PRIMARY KEY (RecordID),
    CONSTRAINT pg_uq UNIQUE (User_ID, GROUP_ID),
    CONSTRAINT pg_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (User_ID) REFERENCES UserList(ID),
    CONSTRAINT pg_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (GROUP_ID) REFERENCES GroupList(ID)
);
```

Comment: The PersonGroup.RecordID field is superfluous. You just need a primary key on the User_ID and Group_ID fields.

Answer (score 0):

A little hard to be totally accurate, but maybe log the ip used to register and then you'll know generally how many accounts came in from that ip.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a RegisteredByID column if it is NULL they registered and then it is easy to find the group also.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a dup of what @Adrian was saying, but I didn't really understand his, so...

When John registers, he gets a user_id, right?

Add a column to the table for a registrar_id.

For the other 20 user records, put John's user_id in the registrar_id column.